# ActiveMQ: How do I limit the number of messages being dispatched?

Tags: activemq-classic

Let's say I have one ActiveMQ Broker and an undefined numbers of consumers.

Problem:

- To process a message, consumers need an external service which is either "DATA1" or "DATA2" (specified in the message)
- Each server, "DATA1" and "DATA2", can only handle 20 connections
- So at most 20 "DATA1" and 20 "DATA2" messages must be dispatched at any time
- Because of priorization, the messages must be enqueued in the same queue
- Even if message A has a higher prio than message B, if A can't be processed because the external service has no free slots, message B needs to be processed instead

How can this be solved? As long as I was using message pulling (prefetch of 0), I was able to do this by using a BrokerPlugin that, on `messagePull`, achieved this by using semaphores and selectors. If the limits were reached, the pull returned `null`.

However, due to performance issues I had to set prefetch to 1 and use push instead. Therefore, my `messagePull` hack no longer works (it's never called).

So far I'm considering implementing a custom Cursor but I was wondering if someone knows a better solution.

**Update** the custom cursor worked but broke features like message removal. I tried with a custom Queue and QueueDispatchSelector (which is a pain to configure since there isn't a proper API to do so) and it mostly works but I still have synchronisation issues.

Also, a very suitable API seems to be DispatchPolicy, however, while it is referenced by Queue, it's never used.

Comment: Did you mean to type '...20 "Data1" and _20_ "Data2"' ? The 3rd bullet point doesn't match up wtih the 2nd.

Comment: If you have concurrent consumers then the processing order of messages is not deterministic. Does that match up with your prioritization requirement for messages of the two types?

Comment: What difference does it make for your consumers to wait for a new message, assuming you achieve your goal of limiting the number of in-flight messages, and waiting for a connection to one of the upstream services to become available?

Comment: Deterministic message order is irrelevant, priority is important. The difference for consumers is: If a message #1 uses DATA1 and has Prio 9 (high) but DATA1 is at its limit, then the consumers must receive message #2 with DATA2 instead, even though it has prio 1 (low), rather than block.

Answer (score 0):

Queues give you buffering for system processing time for free. Messages are delivered on demand. With prefetch=0 or prefetch=1, should effectively get you there. Messages will only be delivered to a consumer when the consumer is ready (ie.. during the consumer.receive() method).

consumer.receive() is a blocking call, so you should not need any custom plugin or other to delay delivery until the consumer process (and its required downstream services) are ready to handle it.

The behavior should work out-of-the-box, or there are some details to your use case that are not provided to shed more light on the scenario.

Comment: Hi Matt, I'm not sure how your answer applies to the situation. Given an unknown number of consumers, the Broker needs to make sure that no more than N messages of a certain type are dispatched. The consumers don't know whether or not DATA1 has free capacity.